# StreamReader, path format not supported

Tags: c#

the path to the text file is (D:>Resit quiz> quiz) I get an error that says "the given path's format is not supported"

```
var pathToFile = @"..\..\..\D:\Files\quiz.txt";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile, true))
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
    {
        QuestNo[x] = questions[pos].QuestionNum = sr.ReadLine();
        for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
        {
            QuestLevel[x] = questions[pos].Level = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
        {
            Quest[x] = questions[pos].Question = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 1; y++)
        {
            QuestAns[x] = questions[pos].answer = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try var pathToFile = @"D:\Files\quiz.txt";

Comment: tried that but it says Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Files\quiz.txt'.

Comment: Check if the file actually exist. Check the folder path. Check if the capital letters and small letters matches as well

Comment: If part of your path contains the root drive what is the purpose of the relative notation ..\..\.. etc.. Really your problem is how you have got that path.

Comment: i've changed the path to libraries>Documents>Visual Studio 2012>Projects>Resit quiz>quiz>Files>questions

Answer (score 0):

You are using the drive letter in the string after using ".." to go up a directory.
This makes no sense at all.

You either go up a directory and then go down into a directory using:

```
@"..\..\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.txt"
```

or you use the full path:

```
@"D:\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.txt"
```

Just don't combine the two.

Remember that when debugging your executable file is in the debug folder, so if the file is not present in the debug folder, you will have to direct to the correct folder the file is in.